# About META Tags: Can not Find Them in Page Source!

Tags: html, seo

I encountered many sites including stackoverflow.com whose page source do not show META tags like keywords, description.

I am just wandering is it because they blocked it by some sort of tech or they just drop them since, as I know, those tags are not so much valuable as before. 
If they blacked them, then what kind of software or tech do they need. If not then how Google extract description from those sites when Google displays search results?

Lot of dumb questions, thanks for your time and reply! 
Any input is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just had a look around on Google .. may be followings help you something.

[Avoid the META keyword tag!](http://www.pandia.com/sew/73-avoid-the-meta-keywords-tag.html)

> Do not use the meta keywords tag. Many
>   people still think of this as a quick
>   fix for SEO. It’s not. Google no
>   longer uses it. In fact, it is likely
>   that Google penalizes sites that do
>   employ the meta keywords tag. Yahoo is
>   perhaps the only search engine that
>   still uses the meta keywords tag but
>   places very little weight on it.

[Death of META Tag](http://searchenginewatch.com/2165061)

pretty old link though

> "In the past we have indexed the meta
>   keywords tag but have found that the
>   high incidence of keyword repetition
>   and spam made it an unreliable
>   indication of site content and
>   quality. We do continue to look at
>   this issue, and may re-include them if
>   the perceived quality improves over
>   time," said Jon Glick, AltaVista's
>   director of internet search.

Comment: "In fact, it is likely that Google penalizes sites that do employ the meta keywords tag." - That claim is unsubstantiated in the article, and I've never heard it anywhere else (including my friends that have worked with and for Google). The rest of the article makes valid points, but that line sounds like shock-value to me.

Answer (score 3):

They're not MATA tags, they're META tags. They are not as important as the actual content of your site and the other sites that link to yours, since it's well known that meta tag content is easier to abuse and misrepresent. Meta elements are more useful in the areas where there is no benefit from such abuse, eg. content encoding or language, but some of this data can be sent by the web server in the HTTP headers anyway. So you rarely, if ever, need any meta elements.

You don't need any sort of technology to 'block' meta tags. Every tag is just a bit of text you insert into your HTML. If you don't want to send out a meta tag, you just don't write it into the HTML.

If you want specific information on how Google views your site then you could start with their [webmasters page](http://www.google.com/webmasters/).